# How to dynamically add/remove .current class to each nav link that is clicked using multiple .html pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Synopsis**

I am attempting to create a sample header navigation that dynamically adds .current class to each menu link that is clicked. I am trying to accomplish this with JavaScript and/or jQuery with multiple .html pages.

**Known bugs to look into**

Right now the .current class simply blinks on briefly when link is clicked, but is removed immediately.

Logged message for which navigation link was clicked does not remain in the console. Currently flashes briefly then is removed immediately.

**Questions**

Is it possible to dynamically add/remove .current class to each link 
that is clicked using multiple .html pages or would I be 
better off using something like MVC or a framework such as angular.js?

Would it be better to have the jQuery reference script at the bottom of the 
page right before the closing body tag?

**Sample Project**

My header navigation look like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="headerNav">
    <li>
      <a id="home" class="headerLink" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="about" class="headerLink" href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My script.js file looks like this.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global document, window, $, jQuery, alert, console, require, logger*/

$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';
  console.log("dom is ready!");
  initHeaderNavLinks();
});

function initHeaderNavLinks() {
  console.log("initializing header nav links...");

  // add current class to first link in header navigation
  $('#headerNav li:first a').addClass("current");
}

$('.headerLink').click(function() {
  var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
  var msg = "";
  msg = "clickedId: " + clickedId;
  console.log(msg);
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Here is my sample project in Plunker.
https://plnkr.co:443/pVPDBfjmhqaIwnMEtMgm

**UPDATE**

For those that are interested, I found a solution that works best for my current needs and simplifies my code. I decided to embed the currentPageID variable directly on each page in a script tag.

**Updated Project**

Added this script tag to the head of each page

```
<script>
  var currentPageID = "about";
</script>
```

My header navigation now look like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="about" href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My script.js file looks like this.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global document, window, $, jQuery, alert, console, require, logger*/

$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';
  console.log("dom is ready!");
  console.log("currentPageID: " + currentPageID);

  $("#" + currentPageID).addClass('current');
});
```

Here is my updated Plunker project https://plnkr.co/pVPDBfjmhqaIwnMEtMgm

Comment: Page is being refreshed as you are clicking on `a` tag which is navigating user on another page and that is resetting the `script`

Comment: To combat what @Rayon said, you can use `localStorage` to store the nav button that was clicked and get that when the page loads. This will require a little more work to be reliable, but that should work. Another thing would be to instead load the `html` pages dynamically to a container on your current page.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same thing Adjit said, but you could use a session variable to hold which link is to have the `current` class.  Set it on your first page load and have each page refer to it when they load.

Comment: Maybe you should not target the click event but add a URL mapping that sets the current class on the matching element on page load.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, but if these are in separate html files, why don't you just make the class of the current selected page, `<a id="home" class="headerLink current" href="index.html">Home</a>`?

Comment: If you want to show in a different way links which were clicked then you should remember `a:visited` class.

Comment: I ended up going with sessionStorage which gave me the solution I was looking for…right now. I may later decide to load the html pages dynamically to a container. The answer that was the most helpful in finding my solution was by @Adjit. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it as the answer. Thank you very much. 

Here is my updated Plunker project with latest changes.
[link](https://plnkr.co:443/pVPDBfjmhqaIwnMEtMgm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be straying away from your current page, you need to have some form of persistence.

You have a few options between Session Storage, Local Storage and Cookies.

**Cookies** are the old fashioned way for web page persistence and generally they are supported by most browsers.

**Session Storage** only stores information for the current session. If the user closes the window, this storage is cleared. Which is probably the most practical for your scenario.

**Local Storage** on the other hand, functions the same was as session storage, however, items in Local Storage have to be explicitly deleted, or the cache is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't write into the page, (in this case i would use html5 data-whatever attributes to keep values, with .dataset.whatever to retrieve).
What you can do is using "#" anchors on your url, then retrieve it with javascript.
And the regular old but robust way for personnal client settings is for sure to use cookies.